# How do i echo rows that have a specific id

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

[its shows in the last part of URL %201 instead of 1 only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YAAC.png)

my view:
`<td><a href="<?php echo site_url('CrudController/edit'); ?>/ <?php echo $row-> id ?>">Edit</a> | Delete </td>`

my controller:

```
public function edit() {
        $this->load->view('crudEdit');
    }
```

Comment: You've got a space between `?>/` and  `<?php echo` - it's getting encoded as `%20`

Comment: @iainn No, more likely that this simply results in an exception indicating a syntax error.

Comment: Check your http server's error log. That is most likely where php errors are getting logged to. That is where you can simply read what the issue is. _Note. you cannot develop a web application without monitoring that log when testing ..._

Comment: @arkascha I'm missing something - the screenshot show a URL with `%201`, and the post suggests that it should only show `1`. The view code provided contains an unnecessary space. Where does anything about a PHP error or exception come from?

Comment: @iainn I would _never_ check such a screenshot or follow any other link posted here which leads to such service. If you do, fine. If that whitespace is encoded, then there are more things broken, since that would mean that this php snippet does not even get interpreted in the first place.

Comment: It's literally a link to an image on the [imgur installation](https://stack.imgur.com/) used by the whole of stackexchange. The whitespace is being encoded because that's what any browser would do for a link containing a space. The space is *outside of the PHP tags* - it's not going to have any effect on code execution

Comment: @arkascha there is no php to interpret. it is just simply 1 character of whitespace in an href attribute. simple as that. of course it will be encoded as %20

Comment: Yes, there is php to interpret. And that is interpreted. And it contains a whitespace which results in a syntax error. The issue here is that there are _two_ whitespace charaters that must not be there. One outside the php code which is converted by the browser, one inside which leads to a syntax error.

Comment: @arkascha I'm really still not sure what syntax error you mean. Are you talking about the space after the arrow in `$row-> id` ? Because while that's admittedly not standard formatting, [it works fine](https://3v4l.org/YmhoR). If you mean something else, it would help everybody if you just said what it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<td><a href="<?php echo site_url('CrudController/edit') . '/' . $row->id; ?>">Edit</a> | Delete </td>
```

Note that there isn't really any reason to close the PHP tag just to display a slash, and then open the PHP tag again--so this should simplify things a bit.

"%20" is the URL encoding for the space character, which is coming from the space after the slash here: `?>/ <?`

So by removing that extra whitespace, everything should work properly :)

Comment: Many thanks, mate! I can't thank you enough, and I also appreciate you explaining everything to me. Have a good day